# iron-data-table selected-item throws 'null' when currently selected item is selected again

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, iron-data-table

In `iron-data-table`, when I click any ***currently selected row***, I expect the `selected-item` (`{{selectedItem}}`) object to reflect the currently (and previously) selected row; but instead, it becomes `null`.

Steps to recreate the problem:

1. [Open this jsBin](http://jsbin.com/xucemijada/1/edit?html,console,output).
2. Select any row.
3. Notice selected object prints to top of page and to console.
4. Select a different row.
5. Notice newly selected item prints to top of page and to console.
6. Clear console. (Optional. Will help you see results of next step.)
7. Click ***currently selected*** row.
8. Notice `selected-item` (`{{selectedItem}}`) object is now `null`.

How can I correct this so the selected object is the newly selected row (which is the previously selected row) and not null?

http://jsbin.com/xucemijada/1/edit?html,console,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
  <head>
    <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+:master/iron-data-table+Saulis+:master/components/">
    <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">

    <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
    <link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">

    <link rel="import" href="iron-data-table/iron-data-table.html">
    <link rel="import" href="iron-data-table/default-styles.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <x-foo></x-foo>
    <dom-module id="x-foo">
      <template>
        <style>
        </style>
        [[_computeSelectedStr(selectedItem)]]

        <iron-ajax
            auto
            url="https://saulis.github.io/iron-data-table/demo/users.json" 
            last-response="{{users}}"
            >
        </iron-ajax>
        <iron-data-table id="grid"
                         selection-enabled
                         items="[[users.results]]"
                         selected-item="{{selectedItem}}"
                         >
          <data-table-column name="Picture" width="50px" flex="0">
            <template>
              <img src="[[item.user.picture.thumbnail]]">
            </template>
          </data-table-column>
          <data-table-column name="First Name">
            <template>[[item.user.name.first]]</template>
          </data-table-column>
          <data-table-column name="Last Name">
            <template>[[item.user.name.last]]</template>
          </data-table-column>
          <data-table-column name="Email">
            <template>[[item.user.email]]</template>
          </data-table-column>
        </iron-data-table>

      </template>
      <script>
        (function(){
              'use strict';
          Polymer({
            is: 'x-foo',
            observers: [
              '_selectedItemChanged(selectedItem)' ,
            ],
            _selectedItemChanged: function(ob) {
              console.log('selectedItem', ob);
            },
            _computeSelectedStr: function(ob) {
              return JSON.stringify(ob);
            },
          });
        })();
      </script>
    </dom-module>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a row is clicked a second time, the item gets deselected and having `null` in `selectedItem` is meant to reflect that. Similarly, in multi-select mode `selectedItems` is empty when nothing is selected.

Since `v1.0.1` `<iron-data-table>` will fire `deselecting-item` event which can be used to prevent deselection.

`table.addEventListener('deselecting-item', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});`

I've updated your JSBin to show an example how to use this event: http://jsbin.com/dubuyoy/edit?html,console,output